# I am trying for creating a user using controller but i am getting an 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
@http.route(['/sell-your-device/user/details'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def ks_user_details_update(self, **kwargs):
     user_partner = request.env.user.partner_id
     vals ={}

     if not request.session.uid:
        # group_user = self.env.ref('base.group_user')

         http.request.env['res.users'].sudo().create({'name': kwargs.get("name"),
                # 'email': kwargs.get('email'),
                'login': kwargs.get('email'),
                # 'groups_id': [(6, 0, [group_user.id])],
                'company_id': request.website.company_id.id,
                'company_ids': [(6, 0, [request.website.company_id.id])],
                'category_id': 1,
                'perm_create': 0,
                'perm_unlink': 0,
                'perm_write': 1,
                'perm_read': 1,
            })
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 208, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 835, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\user\ksolves\custom_addons\sell_device\sell_your_device\controllers\controllers.py", line 485, in ks_user_details_update
    'perm_read': 1,
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 440, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\digest\models\res_users.py", line 12, in create
    user = super(ResUsers, self).create(vals)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 440, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\sales_team\models\res_users.py", line 17, in create
    user = super(ResUsers, self).create(vals)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 440, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\auth_signup\models\res_users.py", line 216, in create
    user = super(ResUsers, self).create(values)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 440, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\res_users.py", line 90, in create
    user = super(Users, self).create(values)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 440, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_users.py", line 1170, in create
    user = super(UsersView, self).create(values)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 461, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_users.py", line 958, in create
    return super(UsersImplied, self).create(vals_list)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_users.py", line 471, in create
    users = super(Users, self.with_context(default_customer=False)).create(vals_list)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3597, in create
    for data in parent_data_list
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\partner_autocomplete\models\res_partner.py", line 168, in create
    partners = super(ResPartner, self).create(vals_list)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\res_partner.py", line 585, in create
    partners = super(Partner, self).create(vals_list)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_thread.py", line 272, in create
    threads = super(MailThread, self).create(vals_list)
  File "C:\Users\user\Ksolves\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 462, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3603, in create
    records = self._create(data_list)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3727, in _create
    for other, data in pycompat.izip(others, data_list)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 2807, in create
    for act in value or []:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There isn't enough context to answer your question. It isn't clear what line is throwing the error. Your code is mostly a definition, and definitions themselves don't actually throw errors unless they are used -- but your code doesn't show how you are using your (fragment of a) definition (although perhaps it is possible that the decorator throws the error when attempting to decorate the method).

Answer (score 0):

its maybe because `value` is an integer, so maybe try to use `range()` to bypass this like:

```
if value:
    for act in range(value):
        pass #replace this with whatever your code
```

you cant implement it like this:

```
for act in range(value) or []:
```

because the `range()` function will raise an error if its a NoneType object and interrupt the running, and if a False bool is given it iters twice, rendering `... or []:` useless and unusable

if you didn't expect `value` to be an integer, then we need to see more to help

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your perm fields. Most likely, instead of using 1/0, you need to use True/False.